# Get list of booleans from a integer value comparison

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking to create a function that returns a list of True and False, from a one value integer compared with a list of integers and I can't figure out how to return the list of True, False from the function.

TIA

Here is my code:

```
num = 7
numListLength = [7, 7, 0]

def compareList():
    for num in numListLength:
        if num == numListLength:
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(compareList())
```

the result I want is a list like this:

```
[True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
num = 7
numListLength = [7, 7, 0]

def compareList():
    return [number == num for number in numListLength]

print(compareList())
# --> [True, True, False]
```

**Note**: In your solution you are returning the value after the first comparison instead you can append the comparison result to a list and return that.

Answer (score 1):

A bit step-to-step piece of code you can find below, with a correction. Also please take a note that your if statement was not entirely correct, and that you've mixed usage of variable n. Example follows:

```
num = 7
numListLength = [7, 7, 0]

def compareList():
    global numListLength
    results = []
    for val in numListLength:
        if val == num:
            results.append(True)
        else:
            results.append(False)
    return results

print(compareList())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` operator and then give a function to compare the numbers of items with the number.

```
num = 7
numListLength = [7, 7, 0]

result = list(map(lambda a: a == num, numListLength))
print(result)
```

will give result `[True, True, False]`